# Can't change Module SDK for libGDX project

Tags: intellij-idea, libgdx

I get "cannot resolve symbol *Bundle*" for a newly created libGDX project in IntelliJ. When comparing this project to one that works, I notice that in the android module, the Module SDK is set to *Project SDK* instead of *Android API*.

If I try to change this I get:

Module "android" must not contain source root "...". 
The root already belongs to the module "android".

---

How can I can't change this and what does the message mean?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you mean by last part, as I didn't do any changes to any of the modules. Anyways I had the same problem - **"cannot resolve symbol android/Bundle etc"**, basically android SDK wasn't included. What I did is simply opened Project Structure > SDKs > Add new Android SDK with correct version e.g. 4.4.2, then pressed ok, and afterwards opened gradle plugin and clicked "Refresh All Gradle Projects". Intellijs rebuilt gradle project and indexed everything. Then android SDK problem was resolved.

Unfortunately this step is not mentioned in the tutorial.